# HTML script button function triggers when opening the window

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I want to make a button where I can see my ip and the button is working, my main problem is that its alerting when opening the page already.

```html
  <p id="ip"></p>
  <button onclick="getIP()">Click me</button>
       <script>
           async function getIP() {
     try {
         const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
         const jsonObj = (res.json()).then(data => alert(data.ip));
     } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
 }
 getIP();
      </script>
```

Comment: So, You want not to invoke function after opening the window, right? You are calling the function `getIP();` in the script. This line cause you call the function when window is loaded

Comment: @BinRohan thanks for explaining thats what I need, hope you have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line of code  **getIP();**

```html
  <p id="ip"></p>
  <button onclick="getIP()">Click me</button>
       <script>
           async function getIP() {
     try {
         const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
         const jsonObj = (res.json()).then(data => alert(data.ip));
     } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
 }
      </script>
```